# clean way to force morphia to overwrite existing entries

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am getting information from a sql DB and moving them into mongo using morphia.  We detect delta changes on the SQL side and import changed values to Monog as well, but my first attempt didn't work because I ended up with both the old and the new entry in the DB, instead of tossing the old entry with the new one.

My next approch was to take the 'sqlID' field and mark it with @id.  This did what I wanted, but it also prevented sqlid from being added as a normal field.  When I want to query mongo for the sqlID the query no longer works.

the other recommendations I found were to do a query to mongo to get the current @id that I can then save over, and to write a custom query that overwrites every field in an existing table if it exists.  I don't like the former option because it would require an extra mongo query for every row I pull from sql, with the data-volume I'm working with that's too expensive.  The later would work, but considering how many fields are in a single record I really don't want to have to manually write out a query to overwrite each one by hand.

My current lazy hack is to save sqlID twice, once as the @id and once as a normal field.  It does what I want, but still feels hack-y (it's a word if I say it is!).

Is there not some easier way of specifying a field and saying "overwrite if this field already exists" when you save to mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd simply create a specialized constructor in my morphia model which takes a DB object as a parameter and do the mapping there, e.g.

```
public MyModel(WhatEverDbObject rdbmsEntity){
  this.idField = rdbmsEntity.sqlId;
  // set the other fields as required
}
```

Next, you could iterate over the changed entities from the RDBMS, creating your entities for MongoDB by simply passing the RDBMS entities to the constructor. Saving them should be as easy as doing an [`updateFirst` with createIfMissing set to `true`](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Updating), with a query on the @Id field.

I can't see why it should be impossible to use your sqlID as @Id. Please check wether your sqlId can be casted to whatever type you used for @Id. If in doubt, simply use String and it should work.

Comment: I could use the sqlID as mongo Id. my problem was that it would save the id differently if it's marked as mongo Id.  there is no longer a sqlID field being created or any way to do a fetch based off of sqlID in the resulting mongo db if I add an mongo Id to it.